# Выбор одинаковых строк

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть строки таблицы вида:

```
<tr group-id="1">...</tr>
<tr group-id="1">...</tr>
<tr group-id="2">...</tr>
<tr group-id="3">...</tr>
```

Как перебрать через **each()** те строки, где **group-id** повторяется ?

Comment: Что Вы уже пытались сделать самостоятельно и где конкретно возникла проблема? Приведите код ваших попыток, добавив его в вопрос, нажав кнопку "править" под вопросом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока сделал так и это решает мою проблему. Может у кого то другого есть лучшие варианты. Минусящему вопрос без конструктива - здоровья в жизни.

```
$('tr').each(function(i,e){
            id = $(this).attr('group-id');
            if ($('tr[group-id='+id+']').length > 1){
                ...
            }
})
```

Comment: отредактируйте свой вопрос и добавьте туда этот текст. минусят подобные вопросы из-за отсутствия каких-либо попыток предоставить собственные варианты решения